# How to unhide or display a pre-hidden menu in html on correct login credentials?

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, onclick

I wish to display a drop down menu in Html on correct login credentials only. If the user enters incorrect login credentials, then the drop down menu should stay hidden due to security reasons.

But the problem is when I enter correct login credentials and validate it through Javascript method, then the drop down menu is displayed just for a second and then it disappears. It just flickers for a moment and hides back.

Can anyone guide me where am I exactly going wrong ?

```
<html>
 <head>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        if ( username == "abc" && password == "123"){
             if(document.getElementById('div2').style.display == 'none'){
                 document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block";
             }

        }
        else{
             document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div id="div1" >
            <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" />

            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" />

            <input type="submit" text="Login" onclick="myFunction()" />
            <input type="reset" text="Reset" />
        </div>


        <select id="div2" style="display: none;">
            <option value="admin">admin</option>
            <option value="courseinstructor">courseinstructor</option>
            <option value="validator">validator</option>
            <option value="papercreator">papercreator</option>  </select>
     </form>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine. Just change the type of your button to "button" instead of "submit". Because of "submit" your page is refreshing again.

From this

```
<input type="submit" text="Login" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

To this

```
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="myFunction()" />
```